# Where can I find A0 or A1 sized maps

Tags: dnd-4e, game-recommendation, battle-map

I am DM'ing a new group in a couple of weeks and I am looking around at finding some simple maps. I love preparing custom maps but this is a group that knows nothing of D&D yet and is being introduced slowly.

We're using the map from the Red-Box, I am using some dungeons tiles to create a small starting hamlet, But I do not feel its enough to keep the group of 7 interested in such a small area. They are from the generation "Video games are cooler" So I am trying to find a larger map so they can see where they are right now and be immersed a little bit more than just with my poor story telling. ;)

Does anyone know of some maps like in the Red Box, that I can print on A0 or A1 paper and offer to my new players for immersions sake? :) I prefer not to build any maps myself using the default tools(Pyromancer etc) as the maps are a one-time thing ;)

Comment: So you're looking for digital maps you'll print yourself? Are you also interested in already-printed maps you buy from a store, or would you prefer only digital ones? (I don't have anything in mind, just good to get those criteria sorted out one way or the other.)

Comment: Buying or printing is fine! :)

Answer (score 2):

I do a generous amount of custom map creation for my campaign. I find that having a mixture of digital and tangible map resources is quite useful.

I do not have any resources specifically sized for A1 or A0 paper; however, many digital maps can be divided up using a tool like [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org) and pasted into a document for printing. I'll confess this is time-consuming, but it afforded me the level of control and customization that I wanted for our campaign.

So, that said, I'll point you to my favorite sites for map resources online. Some of these resources include mostly materials for map designers, but others include beautifully rendered, high-resolution images that can be divided into a document as you please and then printed.

(Note: I hesitate to post this list. There are a great many Internet resources for digital maps, free and commercial, and I feel just a little bad leaving them out. The following are my favorites, which I use regularly, both for original maps and for resources to use in my own maps.)

**My List:**

- [Dundjinni](http://www.dundjinni.com) is mapping software designed for games such as D&D. Even if you are not interested in using their software, they house quite a large community who share their creations and content on the Dundjinni forums. At the moment I'm writing this, their website is delivering a Service Unavailable error. I hope that is short-lived, because I've long appreciated their service.
- [RPGMapShare](http://rpgmapshare.com/) is a website dedicated to sharing free map resources. You'll find a variety of maps, large and small, as well as a decent library of small objects which you can use to spice things up. Some maps are large and high-res, which is convenient if you don't want to do lots of editing yourself.
- [Cartographers' Guild](http://www.cartographersguild.com/) is one of my favorites. This site leans more toward creative cartography in general than it does to D&D-style 1"-to-5' tile maps. If you're looking for something to be your world map or for discussion on general map authoring, this is the place for you.
- [Paizo](http://paizo.com) is a publisher of D&D-related materials, particularly designed for Pathfinder. Their maps, however, are usually very high quality and can be used in most editions and campaign settings. If you simply want to buy something and have it shipped to your door, this publisher is a good choice.